# Python how to show text in a tkinter application on a none-button

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm extremely new to python and has started a small project to learn stuff. anyways, as it says in the title, how do I show text in a tkinter application without creating buttons? here's the code if you need it

```
import tkinter as tk
ulo = 1
hoho = 0
def lul():
    global ulo
    #ulo = ulo + 1
    global  hoho
    hoho = hoho + ulo
    print(hoho)
class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self, fg="green")
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Pressing buttons is fun,\n isn't it?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.lel
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
    def lel(self):
        lul()
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is covered in probably every tkinter tutorial, as well as most tkinter documentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley every tkinter tutorial is either really unclear, uses a outdated python version or just doesn't have an answer to my question. that's why I came here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple options but using [Label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)s are the most fitting one since Label's job is showing text/image.

> The Label widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to display a text
>   or image on the screen. The label can only display text in a single
>   font, but the text may span more than one line.

```
def createWidgets(self):
    self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Pressing buttons is fun, isn't it?")
    self.hi_there = tk.Button(self, fg="green")
    self.hi_there["text"] = "Let's press"
    self.hi_there["command"] = self.lel

    self.lbl.pack()
    self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but not as I thought it would. there is 2 things I need to know now: A: How do I make the label change when a specific variable changes and B: How do I make labels show pictures?

Comment: @Adde21_30 That link I gave in answer actually explains those things. If you scroll down  a bit, there are sections starts with `You can associate a Tkinter variable with a label. When the contents of the variable changes, the label is automatically updated: ` and `You can use the label to display PhotoImage and BitmapImage objects. `

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it doesn't tell me how to use StringVar. I'm sorry for asking these question which their answer may seem obvius, but as I said, I am really new. With both the image command and the StringVar it says "NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined". When I try the image code it says "NameError: name 'PhotoImage' is not defined"

Comment: @Adde21_30 `StringVar` and `PhotoImage` are part of `tkinter`, so you need to call them as `tk.StringVar()` and `tk.PhotoImage()`. Also, no worries, really.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just need to know where to put the files without having to install PIL an i'm done.

Comment: @Adde21_30 You can place them in the same folder with your `xxxx.py` and just use relative path `PhotoImage(file="my_image.gif")` or you can use full path `PhotoImage(file="C:\\Foo\\Bar\\my_image.gif")`. Please note that you can only use GIF and PGM/PPM images without PIL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkinter built-in `Label` widget to display text :

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

def showLabel():
    myLabel=Label(root,text="Hello World")
    myLabel.pack()
myButton=Button(root,text="Click here",command=showLabel)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```